# URL rewriting and sling mappings in AEM

Tags: apache, aem, sling

These are the sling mappings I have under the etc.publish folder:

```
{
  "jcr:primaryType": "sling:Mapping",
  "www_aemsite_com": {
    "sling:internalRedirect": [
      "/content/aemsite/en.html"
    ],
    "jcr:primaryType": "sling:Mapping",
    "sling:match": "www.aemsite.com/$"
  },
  "www.aemsite.com": {
    "sling:internalRedirect": [
      "/content/aemsite/en",
      "/"
    ],
    "jcr:primaryType": "sling:Mapping"
  }
}
```

and these are the rewrite URLs I have in the httpd.conf file:

```
   RewriteRule ^/$ /content/aemsite/en.html [PT,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/content
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content/campaigns
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content/dam   
   RewriteRule !^/content/aemsite/en - [R=404,L,NC]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/apps
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/etc
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/libs
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tmp
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/var
   RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /content/aemsite/en/$1 [PT,L]
```

and I have also configured "Day CQ Link Checker Transformer" to strip HTML extension:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
   jcr:primaryType="sling:OsgiConfig"
   linkcheckertransformer.strictExtensionCheck="{Boolean}false"
   linkcheckertransformer.rewriteElements="[a:href,area:href,form:action]"
   linkcheckertransformer.disableRewriting="{Boolean}false"
   linkcheckertransformer.disableChecking="{Boolean}false"
   linkcheckertransformer.stripHtmltExtension="{Boolean}true"
   linkcheckertransformer.mapCacheSize="{Long}5000"/>
```

I still have some of the things that I am struggling to do:

1) A trailing slash gets appended to the URL. For example, a link that points to http://www.aemsite.com/articles has the "/" appended and therefore I see a blank page. How can I make sure that http://www.aemsite.com/articles gets redirected to http://www.aemsite.com/articles.html internally?

Update: I observed that the dispatcher is able to save the /content/dam and etc folder. I am getting a 403 on web server level while trying to access the pages under http://www.aemsite.com/ as shown below

127.0.0.1 - - [09/Mar/2018:22:26:44 -0500] "GET /articles HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Mar/2018:22:26:44 -0500] "GET /articles/ HTTP/1.1" 403 1

Thanks in advance

Comment: try putting `DirectorySlash Off` inside dispatcher conf in httpd.conf

Comment: I included that but it is still getting appended.